# Is `delete ptr;` necessary in destructor even when memory is not dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, destructor

I have created the following class :

```
class Deep {
private :
    int *ptr;
    string name;
    int age;
    double marks;
public :
    Deep() : ptr {&age}, name {"Mandeep"}, age {20}, marks {85.3} {
        cout<<"Deep Constructor Called for : "<<name<<endl;
    }
    ~Deep() {
        delete ptr;
        cout<<"Destructor Called for : "<<name<<endl;
    }
    void get_data() {
        cout<<"Name : "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Age : "<<*ptr<<endl;
        cout<<"Marks : "<<marks<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    
    Deep A;
    A.get_data();
    
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

While running the program in Debugger, the program crashes at `delete ptr;`.
Is `delete ptr;` no necessary here since I am not dynamically allocating any memory to `*ptr` ?
Is `*ptr` already deleted by the destructor and then me trying to delete `*ptr` after causing the crash ?

Comment: `delete` has to match a `new`. You do not have a `new` in your code, so you cannot use `delete` valid.

Comment: It's not about *necessity* - it's simply wrong to call `delete` on objects not allocated via `new` (like in your example).

Comment: You should not be using `new` or `delete` *at all*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` operator can only be called on objects allocated with `new`. If you haven't allocated `new` memory, you cannot call `delete` operator.

Take the following example:

```
int main() {
    int a = 20;
    int* ptr = &a;
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile this code, it surprisingly(??) compiles without warning.

However, the debugger breaks the code at the call to delete operator.
delete_scalar.cpp:

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept {
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

However, the following code works fine, as the memory has been allocated with `new`:

```
int main() {
    int* ptr = new int[5];
    delete[] ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so the destructor automatically destroys the pointer along with other data members ?

Comment: @LykanMD A pointer is just an address, i.e. a number, there is nothing to destroy. Don't mix destroying a pointer and an object it points to. If you set a pointer to point at some existing object, you shouldn't do anything to destroy the pointer itself.

Comment: @LykanMD This confusion seems to be the source of most newbie problems with pointers. The pointer and the thing it points to are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

‘ptr’ is not pointing to allocated memory so no, you do not want to delete it. Only when ‘ptr’ is “owning” a memory that you need to delete it.